# Temporary failure resolving repository URLs

Tags: 16.04, apt

How to resolve `temporary failure resolving 'dl.google.com'` and `'in.archive.ubuntu.com'` errors?

I have tried using the nameserver for Google (`8.8.8.8`) but the error still remains.

I don't know what to do about this archive error.

Comment: can you post a little more info to your question? please post the command you are running and paste the error into your question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I've encountered this error in the past, it was typically a network configuration issue.

Is your Ubuntu machine's IP address statically or dynamically assigned, and can you access any other websites or machines on your LAN at all?

If it's statically assigned and you can't access anything else either on the internet or your LAN, check your configuration file `/etc/network/interfaces` and try changing it from `iface (name) inet static` to `iface (name) inet dhcp`, and comment out all lines pertaining to that interface, then reboot to see if anything changes.

If you can access your LAN but not the internet, it's likely due to a DNS or default gateway misconfiguration. For a static connection, verify the `gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` line of your `/etc/network/interfaces` file. If your IP address is obtained through DHCP, it's likely a misconfiguration on your networking and not your host.